# How to start a new activity on click in Android?

Tags: android, onclick

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    TextView snt = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.shape_name_text);
    String Selected = snt.getText().toString();
    String triangle = getResources().getString(R.string.triangle);
    if (Selected.equals(triangle)) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TriCalculator.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

My intent is showing several errors and I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: What errors are being shown?

Comment: What error? Show logcat

Comment: Check the error log/window in your IDE (ADT/Eclipse). They should give you information about what is wrong and needs to be fixed. You can jump to the error in most IDEs by double clicking on those error entries.

Comment: did you put onClick on a Button?

Comment: How have you implemented the onClickListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the errors would be helpful but here are at least two:

This line

```
TextView snt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shape_name_text);
```

is telling it to look in the `View` clicked (probably a `Button`) for your `TextView` which it is obviously not there. Assuming `shape_name_text` is in the same `layout as your`Button`just remove`view`

```
TextView snt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shape_name_text);
```

Second problem is in this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TriCalculator.class);
```

`this` refers to the `Listener` if you are in an inner-class. Change that to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TriCalculator.class);
```

**Edit**

As blackbelt pointed out in a comment, the first part of the answer is assuming you have attached the `OnClickListener` on a `View` and not a `ViewGroup` which contains the `View` you are then trying to initialize.

**Another Edit**

It seems (through a deleted comment) that the proper `Intent` import wasn't added

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

Comment: the first part is true only if the `onClickListener` was set on a `View` instance and not on a `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
findViewById(R.id.shape_name_text);
```

remove view.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
TextView snt = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.shape_name_text);
String Selected = snt.getText().toString();
String triangle = getResources().getString(R.string.triangle);
if (Selected.equals(triangle)) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TriCalculator.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

In the code you posted above, you're actually telling the OS that you want to call another OnClickListener, by passing `this` as a parameter for your new `Intent`. In order for it to work, you will need to change it to something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TriCalculator.class);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getAppplicationContext(), TriCalculator.class);
```

(There are other options also)

:) Hope this helps!